# How to define multiple patterns in Frege?

Tags: haskell, frege

I'm having some trouble defining a function in [Frege](https://github.com/Frege/frege) that uses multiple patterns. Basically, I'm defining a mapping by iterating through a list of tuples. I've simplified it down to the following:

```
foo :: a -> [(a, b)] -> b
foo _ [] = [] --nothing found
foo bar (baz, zab):foobar
 | bar == baz = zab
 | otherwise  = foo bar foobar
```

I get the following error:

```
E morse.fr:3: redefinition of `foo` introduced line 2
```

I've seen other examples like [this](https://github.com/Dierk/Real_World_Frege/blob/master/src/main/frege/realworld/experiments/Oopsie.fr) that do use multiple patterns in a function definition, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Why am I getting an error here? I'm new to Frege (and new to Haskell), so there may be something simple I'm missing, but I really don't think this should be a problem.

I'm compiling with version 3.24-7.100.

Comment: You may need to add parens around the `(baz, zab):foobar` pattern. Something like `foo bar ((baz, zab):foobar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure syntactical problem that affects newcomers to languages of the Haskell family. It won't take too long until you internalize the  rule that function application has higher precedence than infix expression.

This has consequences:

- Complex arguments of function application need parentheses.
- In infix expressions, function applications on either side of the operator do not need parentheses (however, individual components of function application may still need them).

In Frege, in addition, the following rule holds:

> The syntax of function application and infix expressions on the left hand side of a definition is identical to the one on the right hand side as far as lexemes allowed on both sides are concerned. (This holds in Haskell only when `@` and `~` are not used.)

This is so you can define an addition function like this:

```
data Number = Z | Succ Number

a + Z      = a
a + Succ b = Succ a + b
```

Hence, when you apply this to your example, you see that syntactically, you're going to redefine the `:` operator. To achieve what you want, you need to write it thus:

```
foo bar ((baz, zab):foobar) = ....
--      ^                 ^
```

This corresponds to the situation where you apply `foo` to a list you are constructing:

```
foo 42 (x:xs)
```

When you write

```
foo 42 x:xs
```

this means

```
(foo 42 x):xs
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you for the detailed answer!